# Replacing an image Flash wants to load

Tags: c#, flash, http, browser, proxy

This is a rather weird question, so please bear with me.

There's a SWF file on one page that, when you click on a 'Start' button loads some image. The URL to this image is passed as a SWFObject variable. I would like to change this image to one I have uploaded on my host.

I have tried setting a breakpoint on the line that pushes the image URL variable to the object and setting my URL, but the image wouldn't load because of cross-domain policy.

Now I am thinking of writing a simple c# proxy which will return my image instead of the real one when Flash requests it ...

Do you perhaps have any better ideas on how this could be done?

**To sum it up, I want to replace an image that SWF loads from a constant URL to a custom image of mine. Decompiling is not an option.**

EDIT: I figured out the image-not-loading problem, it was cached after all.

Comment: Something to note, though I don't have a solution, the Flash Player in Chrome is built-in and automatically updates unless you replace it manually, just mentioning it since you were saying something about clearing the FP caching.  The thing is it should still make the request to see if the file has been modified before using the cached one if that's what it's doing.  So far as I've seen Wireshark shows everything so my thought is that it isn't making the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long for comments: 
It's entirely possible that your SWF file has the image embedded in itself.  However, you say a number of things that sound very conflicting to me.

First off, you mention putting a breakpoint on the line that "pushes the image URL variable to the object"  What, exactly, does this?  Is that the C# code?

You also state that it doesn't load due to cross-domain policy.  Have you resolved that?  Also, why do you think that's the problem?

Why did you try replacing the image with other tools?  Are you trying to manually get around a cross-domain policy restriction?

Finally, you ask state that you "can't figure out why the image packets are not being received."  Before we go that far, are they even being requested?  You mention that wireshark doesn't even see the request going out..

---

I guess all of this boils down to:
1. Do you have control over where the SWF loads the image from?
2. If so, is that request being made?  You should be able to see this from your server logs.

Comment: The SWF and the "default" image are not on my server. I'm sure the image isn't embedded in the SWF file since I have decompiled it and couldn't find it - and I even found the ActionScript2 lines that should load the image.

As for the breakpoint, I'm breaking on the Javascript code that writes the SWFObject to HTML.

Comment: I have chosen your answer since you did kinda help me solve the problem ... I managed to do what I want using Fiddler after all.